# calculating cross entropy manually vs using softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to create a deep ReLU network using tensorflow for the MNIST dataset. It's working fine when I use my loss as the built in ***tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()***, but calculating the entropy term manually doesn't seem to work.

Here is what the network looks like:

```
train_subset = 200
num_features = 784
num_labels = 10
num_units = 200

bias1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_units]), name="bias1")
bias2= tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_units]), name="bias2")
bias3= tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_units]), name="bias3")
bias_out = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_labels]), name="bias_out")

weights1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_features, num_units]), name="weights_layer1")
weights2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_units, num_units]), name="weights_layer2")
weights3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_units, num_units]), name="weights_layer3")
weights_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_units, num_labels]), name="weights_out")

# The deep ReLU network
h_relu1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights1), bias1))
h_relu2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(h_relu1, weights2), bias2))
h_relu3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(h_relu2, weights3), bias3))
logits = tf.matmul(h_relu3, weights_out) + bias_out
```

In other words this works fine:

```
# Assume that y_ is fed a batch of output labels for MNIST
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_labels], name='y-input')
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, y_))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3).minimize(cost)
```

but not this:

```
y = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
cost = -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3).minimize(cost)
```

The latter runs fine, but the accuracy gets stuck after an initial step. The former using the softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits function actually does learn something. I've seen the latter's setup being used for the deep MNIST example, which is why I'm wondering what it is about my setup here that is causing the optimization procedure to stall.

Comment: One issue with the `y_ * tf.log(y)` approach is that it is prone to numerical instability if `y` can be close to 0. However, I'd expect you to see `NaN` results rather than the accuracy getting stuck. Are any gradients being produced at each step?

Comment: Can you try tf.reduce_mean() in your manual cross entropy optimization. Not sure if it's the case but large loss values can cause large gradient steps causing your weights to go back and forth - although I would assume Adam update over time shouldn't be affected by this.

Comment: I just tried looking at the gradients by expanding the line for the optimizer with this: 

`optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(.01).minimize(cost)
 grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)
 optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)`

and ran into more errors. This is a bit strange and not sure what's going on here. As for tf.reduce_mean(), I've tried that as well and not getting any success. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Finally, I can solve this problem with implementing the inside of `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` function by myself, you can find the code [here](https://github.com/AliAbbasi/Numerically-Stable-Cross-Entropy-Loss-Function-Tensorflow) on my GitHub. It is in two version for normal and multi-label problems.

---

**Previous Answer:**

Originally from tensorflow API:

"(Note that in the source code, we don't use this formulation,

`cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))`

because it is numerically unstable. Instead, we apply tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits on the unnormalized logits (e.g., we call softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits on tf.matmul(x, W) + b), because this more numerically stable function internally computes the softmax activation. In your code, consider using tf.nn.(sparse_)softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits instead)"

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/beginners/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a few steps in order to accurately compute your cost. Consider looking at the source code in [`nn_ops.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d489dc57cfa991eb9471945ac3e1a21ccaf02aea/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L1585) to see what else `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` is doing.