# Tensorflow feed_dict not learning

Tags: csv, pandas, numpy, neural-network, tensorflow

Copying and pasting code from tensorflow's MNIST [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html) works just fine, resulting in a ~92% accuracy, as expected.

When I read MNIST data as a CSV, and convert to an np array using pd.DataFrame.values, this process breaks down. I get a ~10% (no better than random) accuracy from this.

Below is the code (tutorial code works well, my CSV reader fails to learn):

**Working** MNIST tutorial:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)


x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})


correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

**Not working** (read CSV and feed np array):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import numpy as np    

# read csv file
MNIST = pd.read_csv("/data.csv")

# pop label column and create training label array
train_label = MNIST.pop("label")

# converts from dataframe to np array
MNIST=MNIST.values

# convert train labels to one hots
train_labels = pd.get_dummies(train_label)
# make np array
train_labels = train_labels.values

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(MNIST,train_labels,test_size=0.2)
# we now have features (x_train) and y values, separated into test and train

# convert to dtype float 32
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = np.array(x_train,dtype='float32'), np.array(x_test,dtype='float32'),np.array(y_train,dtype='float32'),np.array(y_test,dtype='float32')



x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

def get_mini_batch(x,y):
    # choose 100 random row values
    rows=np.random.choice(x.shape[0], 100)
    # return arrays of 100 random rows (for features and labels)
    return x[rows], y[rows]

# train
for i in range(100):
    # get mini batch
    a,b=get_mini_batch(x_train,y_train)
    # run train step, feeding arrays of 100 rows each time
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: a, y_: b})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_test, y_: y_test}))
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. (CSV file [here](https://github.com/wnowak10/MNIST/blob/master/data.csv).)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try training it for more iterations? I see that the original code is training over 1000 iterations

```
for i in range(1000):
```

Whereas the csv code only trains for 100 iterations:

```
for i in range(100):
```

If that's not the reason, it would be helpful if you could also share your CSV file, than we can easily test your code.

**Edit:**

I have tested your code and it seems to be caused by numerical instabilities in the simple `cross_entropy` calculation (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976954/calculating-cross-entropy-manually-vs-using-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logits-in)). Replacing your `cross_entropy` definition by the following line, you be able to resolve the issue:

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    y, y_, name='xentropy')))
```

By also visualizing the returned cross_entropy, you will see that your code returns NaN, whereas with this code you will get real numbers...

The complete working code which also prints out the cross_entropy per iteration:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import numpy as np    

# read csv file
MNIST = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# pop label column and create training label array
train_label = MNIST.pop("label")

# converts from dataframe to np array
MNIST=MNIST.values

# convert train labels to one hots
train_labels = pd.get_dummies(train_label)
# make np array
train_labels = train_labels.values

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(MNIST,train_labels,test_size=0.2)
# we now have features (x_train) and y values, separated into test and train

# convert to dtype float 32
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = np.array(x_train,dtype='float32'), np.array(x_test,dtype='float32'),np.array(y_train,dtype='float32'),np.array(y_test,dtype='float32')

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
print y.get_shape()
print y_.get_shape()
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_, name='xentropy')))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(cross_entropy)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

def get_mini_batch(x,y):
    # choose 100 random row values
    rows=np.random.choice(x.shape[0], 100)
    # return arrays of 100 random rows (for features and labels)
    return x[rows], y[rows]

# train
for i in range(1000):
    # get mini batch
    a,b=get_mini_batch(x_train,y_train)
    # run train step, feeding arrays of 100 rows each time
    _, cost =sess.run([train_step,cross_entropy], feed_dict={x: a, y_: b})
    print cost

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_test, y_: y_test}))
```

You still need to optimize the learning rate and the #iterations further, but with this setting you should already get ~70% accuracy.

Comment: CSV link uploaded. And, alas, no...1000 training interations will results in 10% accuracy with my code.

Comment: When I run this, accuracy drops further. May I ask what accuracy are you getting with this new cross_entropy?

Comment: Sorry, I had an incorrect minus sign in the code, I have an accuracy of 73% now, I will put my complete code in the text! Note that you can still play with learning rate and number of iterations to improve the accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure batches shouldn't be 100 random rows but should be 100 rows that come after each other, for example,  0:99 and 100:199 would be your first two batches. Try this code for the batches. Check this [kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/kakauandme/digit-recognizer/tensorflow-deep-nn) out for training Mnist from csv in TF

```
epochs_completed = 0
index_in_epoch = 0
num_examples = train_images.shape[0]

# serve data by batches
def next_batch(batch_size):

    global train_images
    global train_labels
    global index_in_epoch
    global epochs_completed

    start = index_in_epoch
    index_in_epoch += batch_size

    # when all trainig data have been already used, it is reorder randomly    
    if index_in_epoch > num_examples:
        # finished epoch
        epochs_completed += 1
        # shuffle the data
        perm = np.arange(num_examples)
        np.random.shuffle(perm)
        train_images = train_images[perm]
        train_labels = train_labels[perm]
        # start next epoch
        start = 0
        index_in_epoch = batch_size
        assert batch_size <= num_examples
    end = index_in_epoch
    return train_images[start:end], train_labels[start:end]
```